# Python Line chart

Tags: python, plot

I have a dataframe with three columns. I did a group by on two columns and calculated mean. I reset the index after mean. Now i would like to plot on the graph.

My columns are

```
Type    Time        Value
A   0:15:00     5.3718
    0:30:00     3.4776
    0:45:00     5.6616
    1:00:00     0.1638
    1:15:00     5.2206
    1:30:00     2.6544
    1:45:00     0.2982
    2:00:00     0.1638
B   0:15:00     6.8376
    0:30:00     0.3402
    0:45:00     0.3276
    1:00:00     0.168
    1:15:00     0.252
    1:30:00     6.0858
    1:45:00     0.336
    2:00:00     0.2394
C   0:15:00     0.1638
    0:30:00     0.3276
    0:45:00     0.336
    1:00:00     0.336
    1:15:00     0.168
    1:30:00     0.2394
    1:45:00     0.3402
    2:00:00     0.3318
```

Time on X axis, value on y axis for each type. Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: can you use matplotlib/seaborn?

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

timestamp_list = ['0:15:00','0:30:00','0:45:00','1:00:00','1:15:00','1:30:00','1:45:00','2:00:00']
a_list = [5.3718, 3.4776, 5.6616, 0.1638, 5.2206, 2.6544, 0.2982, 0.1638]
b_list = [6.8376, .03402, 0.3276, 0.168, 0.252, 6.0858, 0.336, 0.2394]
c_list = [0.1638, 0.3276, 0.336, 0.336, 0.168, 0.2394, 0.3402, 0.3318]

plot.plot(timestamp_list, a_list)
plot.plot(timestamp_list, b_list)
plot.plot(timestamp_list, c_list)
plot.xlabel('Time')
plot.show()
```

Basically, I am using `matplotlib` as the plotting module, you can use `pip` to install it if you have not installed it already.

As all of your three types are sharing the same timestamp, so that all we need to do is to put type a, b, c values into their own lists and call `pyplot` to do the plot for you.

Comment: Hi Yu, Thanks for the quick response. For quick reference i have shown TYPE A, B, C but i have many of these types and its a random. There may be hundreds of types. I cannot put all these into lists.